# Comparing two dictionaries in list in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't know how to write the script for comparing two dictionary which are present in a list even though i don't know the dictionary names as well

sample code:
Am i correct or not? if no then please help me to find the solution
Here "dct_list_cluster" is list which contains two dictionaries

**code:**

```
for count in range(len(dct_list_cluster)):
  if dct_list_cluster[count].keys() in dct_list_cluster[count+1].keys():
     fo = open("cluster_" + str(ip_list[count]) + "_output.txt", "a")
     fo.write("\n=> %s" % (dct_list_cluster[key])
```

Comment: I am so sorry to mention that one list is declared before as 
dct_list_cluster = []

Comment: Could you provide sample of the list and expected output it is unclear

Comment: Actually i am storing the json formated output to dictionary & after that i did store that dictionary into a list. so i dont have sample list

Comment: Just give a sample of how it looks and expected output from your part and what output you got when you ran this code

Comment: I did run this code because i am blocked with some other error. I just want to know my logic while comparing in dictionary is ok or not. continue....

Comment: Actually i am giving two IP address in command line then storing that content into a dictionary. Why i am storing is i need to compare some keys of IP1 with IP2

Comment: So by comparing what you want to do that what you want to see

Comment: After comparing i need to write the matched keys into a file

Comment: So you want the keys which match in both the dictionary and there are only two dictionary in the list right

Comment: Yes right. According to my script do you think it will work?

Comment: are you using for loop in it

Comment: Yes i am using for loop as:   
for count in range (0,len(ip_list). then above code starts

Comment: does my answer answer your question

Comment: Yes i got the answer. but if i dont know how many dictionary are present in list then can i go ahead with this  "count+1" concept using for loop

Comment: you want to see if the first dictionary keys are available in all other dictionary `or   you want to see dict1 in dic2 ,dic2 in dic3 etc`

Comment: That is not required as of now. but its good  to learn for me of dict1 is present in dict2,dict2,etc

Comment: SO you want to see if dict1 is present in the next dic that is dic2 and dic2 is present in the next dic and so on till the last dic

Comment: yeah. just for knowledge

Comment: one more thing i don't know what are keys are present in dictionary also

Comment: `dictionary is nothing but key and value pair` that is `key:value` so it has  two thing keys and value.That is value are mapped to keys and there should be no duplicate keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right

You could use `list comprehension`

**code:**

```
lst=[{"a":2,"b":3,"c":4},{"b":4}]
[a for a in lst[0] if a in lst[1]]
['b']
```

Doing it with out `list comprehension`

**code:**

```
lst=[{"a":2,"b":3,"c":4},{"b":4}]
for a in lst[0]:
    if a in lst[1]]:
        print a
```

**output:**

```
b
```

**Operation:**

1.When you are looping over the dictionary you are looping over the keys of the dictionary `there are methods to loop over value and both keys and value`

2.Seeing if it is available in second dictionary if so printing it

**edit:**

```
lst=[{"a":2,"b":3,"c":4},{"b":4},{"b":2,"d":6},{"d":4}]


for count in range(len(lst)-1):
   for a in lst[count]:
      if a in lst[count+1]:
         print "dic"+str(count)+"\t"+str(a)+"\tis common to next dic"
```

**output:**

```
dic0    b       is common to next dic
dic1    b       is common to next dic
dic2    d       is common to next dic
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks Vignesh for more clarity on dictionary.....thanks a lot for your valuable time

Comment: @hari Can you be a little clear on what you want to do

Comment: Yeah things are very clear like i am giving two ip address in command line then i need to convert the json formated output to dictionary & then store that two dictionary into a list & then start macthing. If matching found then write in a file